# How to connect to oracle 12c with php using xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I am currently trying yo connect to oracle 12c, which has been installed on my local machine via php, using a XAMPP server.
I am getting an error stating:

> fatal error call to undefined function oci_connect() in php xampp

PLS help.

Comment: You could alway look [at the documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database)

Comment: Did you download and install the Oracle Instant Client yet?

Comment: Thanks will try tis and let you know.the status.

Comment: Yes I did that too.

Comment: Both x86 and x32 oracle client

Comment: I assume you mean x84 and x64 :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the below extension in your php.ini

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_oci8_11.g.dll
```

by removing the ";" so that the results will below:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_oci8_11.g.dll
```

restart the server after applying changes

Comment: Try to restart php. In some cases php is running in fpm which needs to restart seperately

Comment: Tried restarting the server several times.please help guys I am working on a project and it's very difficult to get the job done without the connection to oracle db.

Comment: I think the OP said `oracle 12c`

Comment: Thanks guys I finally got it working now its getting connected to oracle server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Phillip your documentation was good it helped me a lot.